# Why httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() is not even triggered?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have the following class in which I'm trying to get some data from a specific url.:

```
public static class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: " + params[0]); //Works fine!
        String response = "";
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            Log.d(TAG, "httpURLConnection.getResponseCode(): " + httpURLConnection.getResponseCode()); //Not triggered
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String strings) {}
}
```

And this is how I'm creating the object:

```
String url = "http://...";
MyAsyncTask myAsyncTask = new MyAsyncTask();
myAsyncTask.execute(url);
```

So how can I log the response of `httpURLConnection.getResponseCode()`?

Comment: Don't you get an exception before?

Comment: I do not understand your question, before what?

Comment: Your issue is you don't trigger the log with the response code, so something must happens before this line. An IOException, or a MalformedUrlException being thrown for example. Don't you have any stacktrace at all?

Comment: Oh, yes you're right, I get `Cleartext HTTP traffic to mywebiste.com not permitted`.

Comment: Then you'll get it solved easily with this I guess. Ideally do not use non https calls, but if you are forced to do so there is the solution in this SO post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted

Comment: @XavierFalempin Saved my day, thanks!